# Simply error in C - folders explore

Tags: c

I got problem. Seriously i need help.

I directory SavedGames i got 5 folders

- aa
- bb
- lolgraa
- ffd
- zzzz

And here simply code in C to read what folders are in "SavedGames" and simly put in on screen.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;
  char *array[4];   
  int i = 0;

  dp = opendir ("SavedGames/");
   while (ep = readdir (dp)) 
    {
     array[i++] = ep->d_name;
    }
  closedir (dp);

 puts(array[0]);
 puts(array[1]);
 puts(array[2]);
 puts(array[3]);

 system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

**It returns zzzz, zzzz, zzzz, zzzz, zzzz.**

It seems this is simply error, but i spend on it 2 hour!! :( Thanks

Comment: what are the errors? what have you tried to resolve them?

Comment: What is your error exactly? We cannot guess your errors for you

Comment: Apart from anything else, you seem to have 5 folders

Comment: If you have 5 folders and try to save pointers to their names in an array with capacity for 4 such pointers all bets are off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to allocate memory space while storing the directories.

```
array[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(ep->d_name) + 1);
strcpy(array[i], ep->d_name);
i++;
```

Comment: +1 ... but don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. It is not needed and may hide errors.

Answer (score 0):

`char *array[4];` is an array of 4 pointers to strings.

`readdir` returns a structure containing pointers to strings, all of which is in (process) global memory, the next call to `readdir` replaces the values present.

You are copying the pointer into your array, but that doesn't copy the string.

You need to copy the strings out of the `struct dirent`, and allocate memory to store them in.

Comment: Also if you have 5 strings, you need an array that can hold 5 items.